# Issue when setting Game Screen upon BACK button pressed

Tags: libgdx

I have 3 game screens, saying A, B and C, each extending the `Screen` class. The game normally goes from A to B, and B to C, triggered by click events.

For quick debug purpose, I put the following codes in `ScreenC` 's `render` method, so that when `BACKSPACE` or `BACK` key are pressed I can go back to `ScreenB` from `ScreenC`, and it works fine.

```
if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.BACK) || Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.BACKSPACE)) {
        game.setScreen(new ScreenB(game));
        dispose();
}
```

Now I want to go back from `ScreenB` to `ScreenA`, so I put the following in `ScreenB`'s `render` method, and it works fine, too.

```
if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.BACK) || Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.BACKSPACE)) {
    game.setScreen(new ScreenA(game));
    dispose();
}
```

However, the problem is, now if I press `BACKSPACE` or `BACK` key on `ScreenC`, I will go back to `ScreenA` directly. Seems to me the `keyPressed` event propagated to `ScreenB` from `ScreenC`, so that `ScreenB` detected the event then set to `ScreenA` directly. I am wondering if this is the expected behavior and how do I avoid this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this
`Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.Back)`
and the state isn't maintained just a single consumed event.

`isKeyPressed` is more for character movement i.e. "a" to move left etc